# AltBeacon correlation between RangedBeacon.setSampleExpirationMillisecond, setForegroundScanPeriod and setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod

Tags: android, callback, altbeacon

I'm playing around with the AltBeacon and these parameters. My goal is to have the fastest (as fast as possible) callback `didRangeBeaconsInRegion()`.

I understand that ranging uses running average to calculate the distance and make the callback. I'm not interested in the distance, but the rssi. With that said, if the rssi is varied by 1 that's ok.

In my current code, I currently use:

```
RangedBeacon.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(1000);
try
{
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(700l);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
    mBeaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
}
catch(RemoteException ex)
{
   ...
}
```

My app is in foreground all the time. Running on Nexus 5X.

I notice that the smaller the value for setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(), the more frequent I get the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion()` callback, which is good. The `setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod` is set to 0 which means the service always scans all the time.

In my venue, I have about 30 beacons deployed. With the above code setup, I get callbacks every second, each time a different set of beacons.

The problem is even when I stand right next to a beacon, that beacon is not heard every 1 or less second. When I get the callback, it's usually for other far away beacons. There are times that it takes a good 30 seconds for me to hear that particular beacon to which I'm standing next again.

I know that the beacon we setup chirps every 20ms, so during that 700 ms, I should see them.

I notice that if I raise the `setForegroundScanPeriod` to 5000 (I hope the scan period to be longer so I can get the nearby beacons), I get less callbacks. The delay between callbacks is about 10 seconds. So I think a smaller value means faster callback.

My questions:

1. Why don't I get all the beacons in the callback (they all chirp at 20ms)? How is the callback called? When it has *enough* info, or it has some kind of interval? What controls it?
2. Is there any relationship between `setSampleExpirationMilliseconds`, `setForegroundScanPeriod`, and `setForegroundScanPeriod`? How to make them work well together?
3. My app requires that I *should* hear a nearby beacon (3ft or less) within less than a second, how to best setup the parameters to achieve this?

Thanks for reading such a long question. Appreciate any insights.

@davidgyoung maybe you could shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library isn't designed to give you a callback for every beacon packet detected, but rather to give you regular callbacks at some configured interval to let you know beacons are still around.  By default, this interval is 1100 ms in the foreground, which is configured by

```
setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l); 
setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
```

As soon as the scan period ends, a list of beacon detected in the scan period are returned in a list via the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback.

**You can get faster callbacks by setting a shorter scan period.**  To get callbacks every 500ms, `setForegroundScanPeriod(500l);`  The disadvantage of this is that this stops and restarts BLE scans at the end of each scan period.  (Stopping and restarting is necessary for some Android phone models that can only detect one packet per unique bluetooth MAC address in a single scan cycle.)  But whenever you stop and restart scanning, you will miss any packets that are being transmitted at that exact time -- it's akin to shutting off the bluetooth radio in the middle of the packet.  This leads to a higher percentage of missed packet detections the shorter the scan period.

This may be OK for your use case, provided that the beacon is transmitting every 20ms -- with a 500ms scan interval, you have plenty of samples to ensure a detection.

The `setSampleExpirationMilliseconds` parameter is largely unrelated to what you are trying to do.  It is used for distance estimates when using the default `RunningAverageRssiFilter`.  This setting decides how long to average RSSI measurements for distance estimating purposes.  By default, it retains 20 seconds worth of RSSI samples, which affects the results of `getDistance()` method on `Beacon`.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for your answer. It is much clearer now, as I always thought the `setSampleExpirationMilliseconds` is the one that affects the rate of the callback.

I tried to set `setForegroundScanPeriod(500l)` and the callback rate is not reliable (although it is *generally* faster than 700ms). Some callbacks is delayed by ~500ms, some are delayed by 100ms, some even take 1 sec.

It could be the Android Studio logcat delay. Is it guaranteed that `setForegroundScanPeriod(500l)` is called every 500ms?

Comment: Also, what determines that the library would restart the scan? Is there away to not stopping and restarting the scan that could miss some packets, because I know that almost all the devices we use are modern enough to handle multiple packets.

Comment: I am surprised to hear you say the callbacks are not regular.  I have never seen this.  If you set it to 500l, it should be called every 500ms, delayed by no more than 10ms.  There is no API on the library to disable stopping the scan, although it is a reasonable feature request.  It is a trivial change if you want toodify it yourself to use a custom version.